# CRM 4.0 plugins to CRM 2013 plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, crm

write plugins in crm 4.0 to CRM 2013. I read in MSDN that 4.0 plugins dont work in 2013 CRM. Please give me some suggestions on how to approach this. What will be the major changes I will need to make. Will I need to change the Logic?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would not need to change logic inside of plugins but you will have to change syntax. Check following article - http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/crm-2011-syntax-changes-in-plugins-from-crm-4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code as per CRM 2013 sdk. you need to rewrite custom script, plugin and workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alter any code that is deprecated and also recompile the code against the DLLs contained in the 2013 SDK in order to get your code to run.

To accomplish this I would suggest going through this process in a development environment using CRM 2013 and verify that all the functionality is working. Once you have verified that your functionality is there you can use the plug-ins you created in development for your production system (assuming nothing is hard coded to be environment specific).

Answer (score -1):

The logic of your plugins remain, but all syntaxis is different.
The use of the webservice is different, dynamicentity object doesn't exist anymore. stuff like that.